# Suppose we have two tables How do we take a number `X` from table 1, look-up `X` in table 2 to get Y, Then enter `Y` into table 1

Tags: mysql, sql

This question is about a very basic SQL operation.

We have two tables:

```
+-----------------------+
|      game_results     |
+--------+-------+------+
|  Name  | Score | Rank |
+--------+-------+------+
| David  |   100 | null |
| Jacob  |   100 | null |
| Gordon |  99.9 | null |
| Ian    |  99.9 | null |
| Sarah  |  99.9 | null |
| Robert |  1000 | null |
+--------+-------+------+

+-------+-------+
| ranked_scores |
+-------+-------+
| Score |  Rank |
+-------+-------+
|  1000 |    1  |
|   100 |    2  |
|  99.9 |    3  |
+-------+-------+
```

Our goal is to write some SQL which will fill-in The `Rank` row in the `GAME RESULTS` table.

How do we write SQL to accomplish the following:

1. choose a particular score from the `GAME RESULTS` table (such as 100)
2. look-up that score in the `ranked_scores` table to get a rank (such as 2)
3. then enter the rank into the `GAME RESULTS` table

EXAMPLE:

1. Note that Gordon has score 99.9
2. Look-up 99.9 in the `ranked_scores` table to see that the rank number is 3.
3. Record that Gordon has rank 3 in the `game_results` table.

I wrote the following pseudo-code, but it has for-loops, and does not look at all like **SQL**:

```
for each row `r1` in the table named `game_results` {

    Let `score` be the score value of row `r`

    // Example:
    //     If `r1` is the following row
    //         +--------+-------+------+
    //         | David  |   100 | null |
    //         +--------+-------+------+
    //
    //     then `score` is:
    //         100
    
    Let `reduce_ranked_score` be a new table created from `ranked_scores`
    such that `reduce_ranked_score` only contains the rows where the score
    value is equal to `score`

    For every row `r2` in `reduce_ranked_score`, (r2.Score == score)

    // Example:
    //     if `r1` is the following row
    //         | David  |   100 | null |
    //
    //     then `reduce_ranked_score` is:
    //
    //            +-------+-------+
    //            | Score |  Rank |
    //            +-------+-------+
    //            |   100 |    2  |
    //            +-------+-------+

    Let `rank` be the rank value of the only row in the table named `reduce_ranked_score`

    overwrite `r1.rank` with a copy the value of `rank`

}
```

The following is some SQL I wrote to generate the `ranked_scores` table:

```
CREATE VIEW distinct_scores AS
    SELECT DISTINCT Score
    FROM table_name;

CREATE VIEW ranked_scores AS
    SELECT 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY Score
       ) Rank, 
       Score, 
       Rank
    FROM 
       distinct_scores;
```

Comment: A) what's wrong with just using the view? B) what is not working with `update game_results set rank = (select rank from ranked_scores where score = game_results.score)`?

Answer (score 0):

You would use `update` with a `join`:

```
update game_results gr join
       ranked_scores rs
       on gr.score = rs.score
    set gr.rank = rs.rank
    where rs.score = 100;   -- leave this out if you want to update all scores
```

That said, it is often better to leave the data in two separate tables and to join the tables when you need the information.  Duplicating the same information across multiple tables is considered a bad design practice -- sometimes appropriate, but you should really know what you are doing and why.